# Parse Error on isset? [PHP]

Tags: php, isset

I'm quite new to HTTP/PHP coding and I'm having a little trouble with `isset` in PHP.
This is my current code below, it's supposed to check if the username and password is Admin and Password, if so, it will echo them some info.

However, it doesn't work. There is no errors, it just accepts all usernames and passwords.

```
$username = isset($_POST['password']);
$password = isset($_POST['username']);
$date = date('d-m-y');
$time = date('h:m:s');
$day = date('l');

if($username == 'Admin' and $password == 'Password')
{ //echo bla bla bla..
```

Comment: that's not how you use that function. it's always going to evaluate to TRUE. You want to use a ternary instead if you're going to implement `isset()` like that.

Comment: Read [the manual](http://php.net/isset) and you'll see that `isSet()` returns a boolean (true or false)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isset` just checks if a variable is set. Your usercase, on the otherhand, needs to check the actual values:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) and
   $_POST['username'] == 'Admin' and
   isset($_POST['password']) and
   $_POST['password'] == 'Password') {
   // echo...
```

---

In order to use `isset()` being passed in your variable(s) as you have it now, you need to use a ternary operator.

I.e.:

```
$username = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : "default";
```

- Consult Example #3 and others on
  http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Thank you for this, I see where I went wrong now. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can read the use isset in php [isset](http://php.net/isset) , where it appears that isset has a value of true or false . so the value of the variable $username be true or false , so also in the variable $password. So if you will check value of the POST action you can use

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $date = date('d-m-y');
    $time = date('h:m:s');
    $day = date('l');


  if($username == "Admin" && $password == "Password")
  { //echo bla bla bla..

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
if(isset($_POST['password']) &&  isset($_POST['username'])){

        $username = $_POST['password'];
        $password = $_POST['username'];
        $date = date('d-m-y');
        $time = date('h:m:s');
        $day = date('l');
         //  code here 
                if($username == 'Admin' and $password == 'Password'){

                    // Okay

                }else{

                    // not Okay
                }

    } else {

        // error 
    }
```